# Illegal US Constitutional amendment making itself impervious to judicial review

Tags: constitutional-law, us-constitution, judicial-review, amendment

There are two scenarios where it appears the consideration of the validity of a constitutional amendment would previously require a ruling that it is unconstitutional.

**Scenario 1**: the amendment is kinda similar to the [eleventh amendment](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/amendment-11/), and it prevents the judicial system from challenging the constitutionality of an amendment once it's recognized as part of the Constitution by the Archivist of the United States.

Let's say the Congress adopts this amendment, leaving it in instance before the states, but before any state has taken action on the amendment the Archivist registers it as part of the Constitution. Let's say a suit is filed by some entity having standing on the matter (somehow): the amendment is invalid, because the process of adopting it was illegal, but to even consider its possible invalidity, you have to contradict the amendment's provisions, which means pre-judging it as invalid. Which is kind of a paradox.

**Scenario 2**: the amendment deprives three particular states (Maine, Vermont and Illinois for example) of suffrage in the Senate, and it also prevents the judicial system from taking into account the contents of an amendment when challenging its validity. Let's also assume these two points somehow are written in such a way that it's impossible to separate one from the other without entirely changing the amendment.

This time, the Archivist does nothing as absurd as in the first case, but he files the amendment as part of the Constitution when 3/4th of the states (*not* including Maine, Vermont or Illinois) have ratified it. Same issue: the content of the amendment makes it invalid due to the last clause of [Art. 5](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artV-4-5/ALDE_00013059/) of the Constitution, which forbids amendments preventing equal representation of states in the senate without their consent, but recognizing that implies the same paradox as in scenario 1.

In these scenarios, what could or would the judicial system do? Would it have been possible for the amendment to be blocked between the time it is proposed and the time it's ratified (or considered as such by the Archivist in s.1), or would that be contrary to legislative immunity?

Comment: The plural of scenario is scenarios

Answer (score 3):

Scenario 1.  It doesn’t matter what it says.  If it was not legally ratified, it is not legally in force.  There is no absolutely no paradox at all.  It is essentially just a draft amendment and would be thrown out if any attempt was made to enforce it and challenged.

Comment: Ok, so for example there could be a trial being done without any consideration for 5th amendment rights, if an argument presented during that trial challenged the way that amendment was accepted as part of the constitution, or considered it invalid ? If not, what process would yield to my scenario 1 amendment be considered still a draft, but not the 5th ? (you can take any judicial related amendment instead of the 5th - the bill of rights is probably not the best example)

Comment: @Gouvernathor Sure, but when the court eventually held that the 5th Amendment is valid the entire trial would be thrown out and have to be redone. That’s how a lot of these rules were established in the first place: someone ran a trial without following what was not yet a rule, it got appealed, a higher court said “actually this is a rule,” and the case was sent back to be retried using the new rule.

Comment: @cpast this means that any constitutional right or liberty can be willfully infringed by merely claiming that it's not valid (for the amendments, or overridden for the original articles). In this instance, a higher court (just like the original court) would be going against the very word of the amendment by implying it may be invalid. That enables dangerous potential prejudice when applied to the rights of the accused, to privacy, to equal rights under the law and so on.

Comment: @Gouvernathor I don’t see where you got that idea. When there’s a dispute about whether or not something is the law, a court has to pick *something* to run with while it’s deciding the issue. If it made the wrong decision, then that gets reversed. Obviously a court tries to get it right the first time, but the entire concept of an appeal is “the trial court may have gotten its analysis wrong and here’s how we’ll fix that.”

Comment: @Gouvernathor That’s not to say that “I claim this is invalid” is going to result in a court assuming it’s invalid. A court will try to make the right decision the first time. If you claim the 5th Amendment doesn’t exist, the immediate ruling would be that it does. If you tried to claim that something that obviously hadn’t been ratified was still binding, the immediate ruling would be that it wasn’t binding. In either case, the court or a higher court might reconsider the ruling and say “actually we got it wrong.” But that’s not a problem at all.

Comment: @Gouvernathor there’s no mechanical means to ensure the rule of law is respected. If those in power are determined to misinterpret the law, then that (or insurrection) is what happens.

Answer (score 1):

### First, SCOTUS decides if it has jurisdiction

If these amendments are valid, it does not, if they aren’t, it does. Therefore, it must decide if the amendment is valid. In both cases they clearly aren’t therefore it has jurisdiction to decide that.

Comment: That's the whole point, isn't it ? If you suppose out of nowhere that the amendment is invalid, then they're reviewable and only then can you determine they actually are. But the initial assumption is arbitrary and presumably inconstitutional.

Comment: @Gouvernathor not at all. Courts have the power to decide if a particular case falls within their jurisdiction; even on a law purporting to limit it.

Comment: Where does that power come from, and how is it superior to what the constitution says ?

Comment: @Gouvernathor it comes from section 1 of article iii of the Constitution.

Comment: Sure, but the principle of the constitutional amendment is to override that.